# Am I calling the other classes correctly? I feel like the SnakeBoardDisplay should only be created once

Tags: java, swing

I have 3 separate classes in Java one is for logic, one is painting, and the last is for the window.

Window Class, this class also creates a board display and adds to the window class

```
public SnakeWindow()
{
    this.setTitle("Snake");
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setSize(win_wid, win_hei);

    SnakeBoardDisplay dPanel = new SnakeBoardDisplay();
    this.add(dPanel);
    inintMenu();
    this.setVisible(true);
    setResizable(false);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {

    new SnakeWindow();


}
```

Board Display Class, This class creates a new board display

Where is the proper place for this class to be called and executed?

```
public SnakeBoardDisplay()
{

    game = new SnakeGame();

    tm.start();
    addKeyListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {

    new SnakeBoardDisplay();


}
```

Game Class

```
public SnakeGame()
{
    init();

}

public void init()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < tokens; i++)
    {
        int q = i;

        q *= seperationDis;


        tokensx[i] = CRDX-q;
        tokensy[i] = CRDY;

    }
    sideCollision();
    appleCollision();
    snakeMover();
    bodyCollision();
    apple();
}
```

Declaring the classes

```
public class SnakeGame extends SnakeWindow {

public class SnakeBoardDisplay extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener{

public class SnakeWindow extends JFrame  {
```

Comment: You have two main methods. What is going on?

Comment: Without the main method in the display class I receive and error saying that I am missing the main method.

Comment: Did you ever declare these classes?

Comment: I added the declaration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main class is `SnakeBoardDisplay`. This class has the main method that instantiates the `SnakeGame` in `SnakeBoardDisplay`.

You mentioned:

```
SnakeGame extends SnakeWindow
```

Which means when the `SnakeGame` is instantiated, `SnakeWindow` is also created. You need to call the super class constructor in `SnakeGame` constructor.

```
public SnakeGame()
{
  super(); 
  init();
}
```

Comment: How would I create a new window for the board display?